# How to rewrite URL through htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I rewrite the below url?

> http://www.planethomes.in/project-detail.php?city=mumbai&project=Puraniks-Tokyo-Bay-Phase-1

And I want to rewrite to

```
http://www.planethomes.in/property/mumbai/Puraniks-Tokyo-Bay-Phase-1
```

But it's not happening. My .htaccess file below

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^property/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+) project-detail.php?city={R:1}&amp;project={R:2}

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: RewriteRule is one word

Comment: i have edited my question ,please chk. I have tried with the above that is mentioned

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Turn on rewrite logging in Apache to see why your rule is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `%{QUERY_STRING}`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} city=(.+)&project=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/property/%1/%2 [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Then to internally rewrite the URL back also add below:

```
RewriteRule ^/property/([^/]*)/([^/]*) /project-detail.php?city=$1&project=$2 [L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this. You'll notice I've used `R=301` which is a permanent redirect, I advise using `R=302` while testing as this is a temporary redirect.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Are you getting an error? Is nothing happening? Because I tested this on my own server and it works fine.

Comment: i'm getting 404 page not found

Comment: I've made an edit. Try now. Place this as the top of your `.htaccess`. Remember to place the internal rewrite *below* the other one.

Comment: sorry to say but its also not working. is there any settings to be done outside .htaccess file. I have tried with everything but its not rewriting

Comment: Do you have anything else in your `.htaccess`? Also, have you enabled `mod_rewrite` ? If not, then it will not work.

Comment: i have edited my question along with .htaccess file that i have used earlier. Please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177468/discussion-between-swagatika-and-joe).